# HTML 'required' error firing way too late

Tags: html, required

I have below (much simplified) HTML and javascript code. When I leave the `numDig` field empty and click on the Save button, the `required` error shows up over the input field a little too late, and the page redirects. When the page is already redirecting and loading, the `required` error appears.
Why does this happen and is there a way to fix this? Currently, I can submit the form without filling the required field.

I tried both `button` and `input` but they both do the same thing. The `required` error appears when the page is already redirecting.

```
<script>
    function saveSettings(){
        //More code here
        //and redirect to the previous page
    }
</script>
<form>
    <div class="space">
        <p> Enter the number you like </p>
        <input id="numDig" type="number" min="1" max ="6" required>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
        <button type="submit" onclick="saveSettings()">Save</button>
        <!--<input type="submit" onclick="saveSettings()" value="Save">-->
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the fuction in `onsubmit` for required to take effect properly

```
<form onsubmit="saveSettings()">
    <div class="space">
        <p> Enter the number you like </p>
        <input id="numDig" type="number" min="1" max ="6" required>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
        <input type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! Could you explain to me why your method works but not mine? What exactly is the difference between `onclick="saveSettings()` and `onsubmit="saveSettings()`?

Comment: `required`  specifies that the input field must be filled out before submitting the form with `onsubmit`. This is a javascript built in validation that goes with `onsubmit` and works with button given `type='submit'. `onclick` is just the action you are attaching to the button without extra input validation attached.  Also, `onclick` for the form would just add the click action for the form element without doing anything else so it is redundant to use

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've got a little smarter now!